# Netlify FaunaDB serverless dynamic require errors

Tags: typescript, serverless, netlify, sveltekit, faunadb

trying to get this simple typescript faunadb / netlify serverless function to work

```
// TYPESCRIPT
import faunadb from 'faunadb' /* Import faunaDB sdk */

/* configure faunaDB Client with our secret */
const q = faunadb.query
const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET
})

export const handler = async function (event, context) {

    const t = {success: "success"};
    return  {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(t, null, 2)
    };
};
```

but i keep getting this error after it's deployed

```
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Dynamic require of \"util\" is not supported","trace":["Error: Dynamic require of \"util\" is not supported","    at __require (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:28:9)","    at node_modules/util-deprecate/node.js (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:86:22)","    at __require2 (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:31:44)","    at node_modules/faunadb/src/query.js (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:6328:21)","    at __require2 (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:31:44)","    at node_modules/faunadb/index.js (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:8742:17)","    at __require2 (file:///var/task/functions/play.js:31:44)","    at file:///var/task/functions/play.js:8760:33","    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:183:25)","    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:60:5)"]}
```

any ideas?

** Edit
Looks like this is a problem with Netlify's serverless typescript support. Compiling the typescript functions into their .js counterparts works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem with Netlify's serverless typescript support. Compiling the typescript functions into their .js counterparts works as intended

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).